# Подключение TextBox

Tags: c#

подскажите как настроить, что бы при выборе чекбокса и нажатии кнопки, происходил рассчет в текстбоксах.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;

        a = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        b = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);

        b = a * 75;
        c = a * 65;

        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(c);
    }

    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        int a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int c = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        b = a * 77;
        c = a * 65;
        textBox2.Text = b.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = c.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сейчас что не так ? вроде у вас обработчик кнопки подключен, расчеты в какой то текстбокс выводятся(про внешний вид кода промолчу)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Там где тип курса выбираете, используйте [`RadioButton`](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.5.php) вместо `CheckBox`. Кстати, по этий ссылке и ответ на свой вопрос найдете.